# Getting error while returning an object of type JsonArray

Tags: java, json

I want to create a `JsonArray`  from different `JsonObject`  but I keep getting an error when i try to return the final `JsonArray`

> "Type definition error: [simple type, class org.json.JSONObject]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)"

myFunction :

```
@GetMapping("/statSysteme")
public JSONArray statSysteme() {
    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();

    List<MaBase> myList=(List<MaBase>) maBaseRepos.findAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(myList.get(i).getMyText().getTheme().getSysteme().getNomSysteme()+"///"+myList.get(i).getStatusConformité());
        JSONObject ja = new JSONObject();
        ja.put("Nom Systeme",myList.get(i).getMyText().getTheme().getSysteme().getNomSysteme());
        ja.put("Status Conformite",myList.get(i).getStatusConformité());
        jsonArray.put(ja);
        System.out.println(ja);
    }


    return jsonArray;
}
```

Comment: can it be you get some not serializable values for ja."Nom Systeme" or/and for ja."Status Conformite"? Of which types are these values?

Comment: supposed to be strings

Comment: It's not obvious from the code. Can you check these presicely? If you put *.toString()* at the end of both call trains, will the problem survive?

Comment: Yes they are strings

Comment: it seems that the put function does not accept( string, string )

Comment: Strings are supported both for JSONArray and for JSONObject But. When exactly do you get the error? At wich line ofthe code snippet? Asking cause pretty similar code works for me.

Comment: @lotor as i just found like i told you it seems that when i put a double string in the put function of the jsonobject that's what makes the error because it doesn't accept two string it only accept ( string , long ) ( string , double) etc

Comment: Guys, the whole json idea are mosly about strings. Both JSONArray.put(Object) and JSONObject.put(String, Object) are declared directly that String is a legal type.My last question was not about reasons, but about direct place in stacktrace.

Comment: @lotor well i just found another solution man i create a list of jsonObjects instead of jsonArray

Comment: No serializer found fo JSONOIbject - that looks suspicious. Does it sounds similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061781/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-json-jsonobject-and-no-properties-discovered-t